# Warning: Use the `defaultValue` or `value` props on <select> instead of setting `selected` on <option>. in dropdown

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have this JSON returned from the server:

```
[
   {
      "symbol":"one option"
   },
   {
      "symbol":"second option"
   }
   .......
]
```

I tried to display the data into dropdown using:

```
<Select                            
    value={props.selectedData}>
    {props.availableData.map((option) => (
        <option value={option.symbol}>{option.symbol}</option>
    ))}
</Select>
```

But I get error:

```
Warning: Use the `defaultValue` or `value` props on <select> instead of setting `selected` on <option>.
```

Do you know how I can fix this?

Comment: Can you please add more info/code about <Select> component? Are you using any third party component library like mui/material-ui?

Comment: I get this error: `Warning: Each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop.` Maybe this is causing the issue?

Comment: No. This is not causing the issue.

Comment: To avoid Warning: Each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop.
 you can modify:

<option key={option.symbol} value={option.symbol}>{option.symbol}</option>

learn more: https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html

Comment: Again I get `Warning: Each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop.` and `Warning: Use the `defaultValue` or `value` props on <select> instead of setting `selected` on <option>.`